# Labelling points with ggrepel using a second dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I have two lines that I wish to label with `ggrepel`.
I require a second, separate dataframe to have the label information.

The error I get is:

```
Error in `geom_label_repel()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'comp' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I thought when I assign new data to `geom_label_repel(data = comp_label_df` the old dataframe, `df`, would not be referenced. That is why I am puzzled by the error that refers to `comp` which is a column header in `df`.

How do I label the two lines at x = "2023-01-08"?

```
library("tidyverse")
library("ggrepel")

d1 <- as.Date("2023-01-07")
d2 <- as.Date("2023-01-08")
d3 <- as.Date("2023-01-09")

comp_label_df <- tibble(
  x = c(d2, d2),
  one = c(1.3, 2.5),
  label = c("Line 1", "Line 2")
)

df <- tibble(
  comp = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
  one = c(1, 1.1, 1.3, 2.5, 5, 8),
  date = c(d1, d1, d2, d2, d3, d3)
)

# OK
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date, y = one, group = comp)) +
  geom_line() 

# ERROR
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date, y = one, group = comp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label_repel(data = comp_label_df, aes(x = x, y = one, label = label))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aesthetics are passed on to lower layers if defined at the parent level. Since `comp` is not present in `comp_label_df` it returns an error. Specify aesthetics at `geom` level.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = one, group = comp)) +
  geom_label_repel(data = comp_label_df, aes(x = x, y = one, label = label))
```

[image]